# MongoDB - Unset an attribute from a single array element

Tags: mongodb

How can I unset an attribute from a single array element from the Mongo console.
For example, how do I unset the junk attribute from time[1]

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4d525ab2924f0000000022ad"), 
  "name" : "hello", 
  "time" : [
      {
          "stamp" : "2010-07-01T12:01:03.75+02:00",
          "reason" : "new"
      },
      {
          "stamp" : "2010-07-02T16:03:48.187+03:00",
          "reason" : "update",
          "junk"  : "yes"
      },
      {
          "stamp" : "2010-07-02T16:03:48.187+04:00",
          "reason" : "update"
      },

   ]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
db.coll.update({"time.junk": "yes"}, {$unset: {"time.$.junk": 1}});
```

Read on [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation).

Comment: Actually it will remove the value, BUT only from the first occurrence of the subdocument, because "the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document" (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#query)

Also: see Hassek's hack here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945924/remove-a-field-from-array-element-in-mongodb