# Remove a field from all elements in array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have below document in MongoDB(2.4.5)

```
{
    "_id" : 235399,
    "casts" : {
        "crew" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : 1186343,
                "withBase" : true,
                "department" : "Directing",
                "job" : "Director",
                "name" : "Connie Rasinski"
            },
            {
                "_id" : 86342,
                "withBase" : true
            }
        ]
    },
    "likes" : 0,
    "rating" : 0,
    "rating_count" : 0,
    "release_date" : "1955-11-11"
}
```

I want to remove withBase filed from array elements inside casts.crew ..

I tried this

```
db.coll.update({_id:235399},{$unset: {  "casts.crew.withBase" : 1 } },false,true)
```

nothing changed.

And tried this..

```
db.coll.update({_id:235399},{$unset: {  "casts.crew" : { $elemMatch: { "withBase": 1 } } } },false,true)
```

it removed entire crew array from the document.

Can someone please provide me the right query?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you, but your answer

```
db.coll.update({
   _id:235399,
   "casts.crew.withBase": {$exists: true}
},{
   $unset: {
      "casts.crew.$.withBase" : true
   }
},false,true)
```

is not correct. Actually it will remove the value, BUT only from the first occurrence of the subdocument, because of the way [positional operator works](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#query):

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element
>   that matches the query document

You also can not use `$unset` (as you tried before) because it can not work on arrays (and are you basically trying to remove a key from a document from the array). You also can not remove it with `$pull`, because pull removes all the array, not just a field of it.

Therefore as far as I know you can not do this with a simple operator. So the last resort is doing `$find` and then `forEach` with save. You can see [how to do this in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19824993/1090562). In your case you need to have another loop in `forEach` function to iterate through array and to [delete a key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455416/1090562). I hope that you will be able to modify it. If no, I will try to help you.

P.S. If someone looks a way to do this - here is **Sandra's function**

```
db.coll.find({_id:235399}).forEach( function(doc) {
  var arr = doc.casts.crew;
  var length = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    delete arr[i]["withBase"];
  }
  db.coll.save(doc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Salvador. It worked.. Here is my function `db.coll.find({_id:235399}).forEach( function(doc) {
 var arr =  doc.casts.cast; 
 var length  = arr.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  delete arr[i]["withBase"];
     
} 
db.coll.save(doc); } );`

Comment: Glad that it helped. I will add it to my answer with your credentials.

Comment: A more functional approach to Nancy's solution is:

`db.coll.find({_id:235399}).forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.casts.crew.forEach(function(crew) {
    delete crew.withBase;
  })

  db.coll.save(doc);
});`

Comment: Be aware this isn't transaction save. Any changes occuring after `find()` and before `save()` will be overwritten. Prefer [Veeram's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47836562/4029989), if you you have MongoDB 3.6+.

Comment: See user2683814 answer

Answer (score 107):

You can use the new [`positional identifier`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to update multiple elements in array in 3.6.

Something like

```
 db.coll.update( {_id:235399}, {$unset: {"casts.crew.$[].withBase":""}} )
```

[$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]) removes all the `withBase` property from the `crews` array. It acts as a placeholder for updating all elements in array.

Use multi true to affect multiple documents.

Comment: Please don't downvote without explanation. Will be happy to address your concern.

Comment: sorry I downvoted this, I can't un-downvote :) - this actually _does_ work, but only for mongodb >=3.6. And it also work with `updateMany()`

Comment: @mils Added version in the answer.

Comment: This is the correct link to the documentation of the "update all array elements" operator : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: simple and clear answer. Good job!

Comment: db.alimentos.updateMany( {_id: ObjectId("5fb9f282d742c3e6884a8000")}, {$unset: {"proteins.$[].id":""}} )  in my protein array I have objects and each with id added, I needed to delete it in 42 docs, I need to write that way   MongoDB shell version v4.4.2

Comment: This positional operator `$[]` worked for me :+1:

Comment: +1 Works fine in my case to remove element in all documents: `db.coll.update({}, {$unset: {"casts.crew.$[].withBase":""}}, {"multi:true"})`

Answer (score 14):

I found a way to unset this lists without having to pull up the object (meaning, just doing an update), it's pretty hackish but if you have a huge database it will make the deal:

```
db.coll.update({},{$unset: {"casts.crew.0.withBase" : 1, "casts.crew.1.withBase" : 1} }, {multi: 1})
```

In other words, you have to calculate how many objects there can be in any of your documents list and add those numbers explicitly, in this case as `{casts.crew.NUMBER.withBase: 1}`.

Also, to count the longest array in a mongodb object, an aggregate can be done, something like this:

```
db.coll.aggregate( [   { $unwind : "$casts.crew" },   { $group : { _id : "$_id", len : { $sum : 1 } } },   { $sort : { len : -1 } },   { $limit : 1 } ], {allowDiskUse: true} )
```

Just want to emphasize that this is not a pretty solution but is way faster than fetching and saving.