# MongoDB how to remove field inside embedded array?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I have a situation where i want to remove a field inside a array of dictionary.

I know how to remove a normal field:
{ $unset: { : ""} }

But please help me for below example where i want to remove **status** field inside second dict

```
{  
    "recs":[  
        {  
            "required_1":""
            "required_2":"info",
            "status":"completed",
            "datetime":"2018-02-02T06:00:04Z"
        },
        {  
            "required_1":""
            "required_2":"info",
            "status":"inprogress"
            "datetime":"2018-02-02T06:00:04Z"         
        }
    ],
    "mainstatus":"failed"
}
```

Comment: *Only* inside the second dict, not the first dict?

Comment: Yes i want to delete from second dict. I want to delete if status is "inprogress" which is only there in second record

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945924/remove-a-field-from-all-elements-in-array-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `$` sign : `recs.$.status` will select the `status` field of all records in `recs`.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Answer (score -1):

You have to use $pull to remove data from the array.

```
db.getCollection('TEST').update({/* some condition */}, {
    $pull: {
        recs: {"status" : "inprogress"}
    }
});
```