# MongoDB, remove nested items from objects in arrays

Tags: mongodb, unset

Here's my data structure:

```
db.getCollection('competitionmatches').find()
```

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2d9eed5972a9367cd5010a"),
    "matches" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 200000,
            "utcDate" : "",
            "minute" : null,
            "homeTeam" : {
                "id" : 808,
                "coach" : {},
            },
            "goals" : [{},{}}],
        },
        {...},
        {...},
    ],
    "otherField": []
},
{...},
{...},
```

What i'm trying to remove are those fields: `minute`, `coach` and `goals` in all `matches` of all entries in `competitionmatches`.

I've tried the following in Robo 3T with success:

```
db.getCollection('competitionmatches').update({}, {$unset: {"otherField":""}})
```

This removes well the whole array `otherField` in each element of `matches` if i pass `multi:true` (removed here for the sake of readability).

But when i try:

```
db.getCollection('competitionmatches').update({}, {$unset: {"matches.$[].goals":""}})
```

or

```
db.getCollection('competitionmatches').update({}, {$unset: {"matches.$[].minute":""}})
```

i get a success message `Updated 1 existing record(s) in 3ms` but the record stay the same, `minute` or `goals` do not get removed.

I got this answer from [Remove a field from all elements in array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945924/remove-a-field-from-all-elements-in-array-in-mongodb/47836562#47836562) and updated my mongo version from 3.4 to 3.6 because the `$[]` was introduced in 3.6 as said by [svr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/svr) and shown in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_%5B%5D).

Unset works but the path seems to be the wrong part of my update.

`"matches.$.goals"` returns an error and `matches.[].goals` does not have any impact as well.
I was even wondering if there could be some cache but that does not make much sense since the unset on `otherField` gets executed well.

I was also in doubt if the update went well but the app using the database works fine as far as i can see.

Answer (score 2):

The update can't access direct array field using `$` or `$[]`, we need to provide query to match in array,

```
db.getCollection('competitionmatches').update(
  // it requires to specify any one field match condition in query part
  { "matches.goals": { $exists: true } }, 
  { 
    $unset: { 
      "matches.$[].minute": true // pass true
      "matches.$[].homeTeam.coach": true // pass true
      "matches.$[].goals": true // pass true
    } 
  } 
);
```

**Mongo shell**

```js
> db.upd22.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5d2d9eed5972a9367cd5010a"),
    matches: [
      {
        id: 200000,
        utcDate: '',
        minute: null,
        homeTeam: { id: 808, coach: {} },
        goals: [ {}, {} ]
      },
      {
        id: 300000,
        utcDate: '',
        minute: null,
        homeTeam: { id: 808, coach: {} },
        goals: [ {}, {} ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5d2d9eed5972a9367cd5010b"),
    matches: [
      {
        id: 400000,
        utcDate: '',
        minute: null,
        homeTeam: { id: 808, coach: {} },
        goals: [ {}, {} ]
      },
      {
        id: 500000,
        utcDate: '',
>                                                                                                                                          homeTeam: { id: 808, coach: {} },
        goals: [ {}, {} ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
> db.getCollection('upd22').update(
...     { "matches.goals": { $exists: true } },
...     {
.....         $unset: {
.......             "matches.$[].minute": true,
.......             "matches.$[].goals": true
.......         }
.....     },
...     { multi: false }
... )
{
  acknowledged: 1,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedCount: 0
}
> db.upd22.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5d2d9eed5972a9367cd5010a"),
    matches: [
      { id: 200000, utcDate: '', homeTeam: { id: 808, coach: {} } },
      { id: 300000, utcDate: '', homeTeam: { id: 808, coach: {} } }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5d2d9eed5972a9367cd5010b"),
    matches: [
      {
        id: 400000,
        utcDate: '',
        minute: null,
        homeTeam: { id: 808, coach: {} },
        goals: [ {}, {} ]
      },
      {
        id: 500000,
        utcDate: '',
        minute: null,
        homeTeam: { id: 808, coach: {} },
        goals: [ {}, {} ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
>
```

Comment: Just tried but no luck. I used the following:`db.getCollection('competitionmatches').update({ "matches.goals": { $exists: true } }, { $unset: { "matches.$[].minute": true, "matches.$[].goals": true}} , { multi:false })`
Note, `coach` is within the `homeTeam` object.

Comment: its removing both fields from first document, that is not working your side?

Comment: i get an "Updated 1 existing record(s)" as the result but when refreshing the data with a new `find()` i can still  see bopth fields in at least the first two entries of the array `matches`.

Comment: I've narrowed the query to a specific `competitionMatches` by id with `db.getCollection('competitionmatches').update({ "_id": ObjectId("5d2d9eed5972a9367cd5010a"), "matches.goals": { $exists: true } }, { $unset: { "matches.$[].minute": true, "matches.$[].goals": true}} , { multi:false })`

Comment: Just did a quick test by adding at the root of the `competitionMatches` with the id above a field `temporary` and removing it with `db.getCollection('competitionmatches').update({ "_id": ObjectId("5d2d9eed5972a9367cd5010a"), "matches.goals": { $exists: true } }, { $unset: { "tempo":true, "matches.$[].minute": true, "matches.$[].goals": true}} , { multi:false })` and it worked. So i guess the problem os really entering the array and finding the desired fields.

Comment: not sure why its not working in your machine, might be some versioning issues.